# Excel- Subtract a number from an array and sum the absolute value up for each cell

Tags: excel-formula

I want to lessen a calculated number from each cells of an array, and then
sum the absolute value of each of the differences all.
The case is that I want to formulate this in Excel.

For example, you have an array with, {1,3,4,5,6,6,7,2} and you want to
subtract 2.5 from each, use the absolute difference of each and sum all the differences up.

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A1:A8-2.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent formula golf.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an array formula of

```
=SUM(ABS(A1:A8-2.5))
```

Entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Curly braces `{}` should appear around formula.